# Can a foreign key index be part of another index or should it be standalone?

Tags: oracle, indexing, foreign-keys

I have an index organized table in Oracle 18 with the primary key

PRIMARY KEY
(ISSUE_ID, LOCATION_ID_FIN, PRODUCTNUMBER, LOCATION_ID_COMPONENT, LOCAL_PART_NUMBER)

There is an foreign key to the issues table (issue_id)
and two towards the locations table (LOCATION_ID_FIN and LOCATION_ID_COMPONENT).

I would not create a separate index on issue_id, because it is on first place,
but should I create separate foreign key indexes for LOCATION_ID_FIN and LOCATION_ID_COMPONENT
or is it enough that those columns are contained in the primary key?

(this question assumes that a foreign key index is needed to avoid any locking (tm-contention))

Database Version is 18, migrating to 19c the next weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need the index that starts with the foreign key columns.  A way to prove this (from Tom Kyte's book Expert One-On-One Oracle) is to do this:

```
alter table issues disable table lock;
```

Now if you try to update the parent table like this:

```
update locations set location_id_fin = <new value>;
```

you will get this error:

> ORA-00069: cannot acquire lock -- table locks disabled for CHILD

However once you add the index that begins with the foreign key columns then you will get the expected error:

> ORA-02292: integrity constraint (xxx) violated - child record found